# Parsing regex with escaped pipe delimiter

Tags: regex

Im trying to parse

```
|123|create|item|1497359166334|Sport|Some League|\|Team\| vs \|Team\||1497359216693|
```

With regex (https://regex101.com/r/KLzIOa/1/)

I currently have

```
[^|]++
```

Which is parsing everything correctly except `\|Team\| vs \|Team\|`

I would expect this to be parsed as `|Team| vs |Team|`

If i change the regex to

```
[^\\|]++
```

It parses the Teams separately instead of together with the escaped pipe

Basically i want to parse the fields between the pipes however, if there are any escaped pipes i would like to capture them. So with my example i would expect

```
["123", "create", "item", "1497359166334", "Sport", "Some League", "|Team| vs |Team|", "1497359216693"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alternate between:

- `\\.` - A literal backslash followed by anything, or
- `[^|\\]+` - Anything but a pipe or backslash

```
(?:\\.|[^|\\]+)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/KLzIOa/2

Note that there's no need for the possessive quantifier, because no backtracking will occur.

If you also want to replace `\|`s with `|`s, then do that afterwards: match `\\\|` and replace with `|`.

Comment: In this situation `\|Team\| vs \|Team\|` is captured. Would that mean i would have to remove the `\` myself after manually?

Comment: A regular expression can generally *match* substrings, or *replace* part of a match, but not do both at the same time. If you want to replace the `\|`s with `|`s, you'll have to do that afterwards.

Comment: what if I want to capture empty values as well? I mean when pipe is placed after another one

Comment: @EgorBaranov Alternate the whole pattern with another that matches between two pipes. `(?<=\|)(?=\|)`

Answer (score 1):

To handle escaping, you should match a backslash and the character after it as a single "item".

```
(?:\\.|[^|])++
```

This conveniently also works for escaping the backslashes themselves!

To then remove the backslashes from the results, use a simple replacement:

```
Replace: \\(.)
With: $1
```

Comment: In this situation `\|Team\| vs \|Team\|` is captured. Would that mean i would have to remove the `` myself after manually?

Comment: Yes, you would indeed need to do that. Replace `\\(.)` with `$1`.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
(?:\\\||[^|])+
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/KLzIOa/4)

Comment: @Tomalak: True, I've just copied OP's regex.